# SQL Server 2008 R2: Pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE pvt
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(10)
)

insert into pvt values('','2');
insert into pvt values('1','3');
insert into pvt values('9','4');
insert into pvt values('8','5');
```

**Pivot table Query**:

```
DECLARE @StuffColumn varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(cola) 
                        FROM pvt
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@StuffColumn)        

SET @SQL = ' select colb,'+ @StuffColumn +'
         from
         (
            select cola,colb
            from pvt
         )x
         pivot
         (
             count(cola)
             for cola in( '+@StuffColumn +')
         )p'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Error**:

```
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, 
verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias 
names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
```

**Expected Result**:

```
colb      1  9   8       
-------------------
 2    1   0  0   0
 3    0   1  0   0
 4    0   0  1   0
 5    0   0  0   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @StuffColumn varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(case when cola = '' then 'empty' else cola end) 
                        FROM pvt
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@StuffColumn)        

SET @SQL = ' select colb,'+ @StuffColumn +'
         from
         (
            select case when cola = '''' then ''empty'' else cola end as cola,colb
            from pvt
         )x
         pivot
         (
             count(cola)
             for cola in( '+@StuffColumn +')
         )p'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

You need to give name to your pivot columns.

Solution for more than one empty column + dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @StuffColumn varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(case when cola = '' then Cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by colb) as varchar (6))  + 'empty' else cola end) 
                        FROM pvt
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@StuffColumn)        

SET @SQL = ' select colb,'+ @StuffColumn +'
         from
         (
            select   case when cola = '''' then Cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by colb) as varchar (6)) +''empty'' else cola end cola,colb
            from pvt
         )x
         pivot
         (
             count(cola)
             for cola in( '+@StuffColumn +')
         )p'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aad5/2)

Comment: Very near! Only count is not appearing into the `[empty]` column.

Comment: Problem with this is if you have multiple empty values.

Comment: @NMK, Exactly! There is problem with multiple empty columns

Comment: @Milen Pavlov, Just awesome! Can't believe that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Milen Pavlov, Getting columns '21  39  48` instead of `2  3  4'.

Comment: edited my answer to only append row number for empty columns :)

Comment: @Milen Pavlov, Sorry for late replay. Yeah! I got it. Thank you so much. :)